# Using the output from a User Form in the macro with IF structure

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to merge 4 models into one. All models have a common part of the code as well as a model specific parts. I have created a user form, which identifies what model to run based on the criteria selected by user. So the user form has 4 criteria and produces 12 different outcomes. So I want to create a sub which will run the commons parts of the code for all outcomes and then outcome specific parts.

Currently the user form code displays message boxes depending on the selection. I want to connect this code (see it below) to the code in the VBA model and use in the IF structure. For example, if a user select Template 1, Private data type and Tier 2, No Wipe Out then the model will run the common part, then the parts for Template 1 with Private data type, Tier 2 and No  Wipe Out and then again a common part.

For example, the Wipe Out/No Wipe Out part is similar for all models. Other parts have a lot of similarities.

Here is the User Form code:

```
Private Sub modelrun_btn_Click()

If radiotempl1.Value = True Then
    If datatype.Value = "Public" Then
        If wipe_format.Value = True Then
                MsgBox "Template 1 Public Model Wipe Out"
        Else
                MsgBox "Template 1 Public Model No Wipe Out"
        End If
    ElseIf datatype.Value = "Private" Then
        If radiotier1.Value = True Then
            If wipe_format.Value = True Then
                MsgBox "Template 1 Private Model Tier 1 Wipe Out"
            Else
                MsgBox "Template 1 Private Model Tier 1 No Wipe Out"
            End If
        Else
            If wipe_format.Value = True Then
                MsgBox "Template 1 Private Model Tier 2 Wipe Out"
            Else
                MsgBox "Template 1 Private Model Tier 2 No Wipe Out"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a data type"
    End If
ElseIf radiotempl2.Value = True Then
    If datatype.Value = "Public" Then
        If wipe_format.Value = True Then
            MsgBox "Template 2 Public Model Wipe Out"
        Else
            MsgBox "Template 2 Public Model No Wipe Out"
        End If
     ElseIf datatype.Value = "Private" Then
        If radiotier1.Value = True Then
            If wipe_format.Value = True Then
                MsgBox "Template 2 Private Model Tier 1 Wipe Out"
            Else
                MsgBox "Template 2 Private Model Tier 1 No Wipe Out"
            End If
        ElseIf radiotier2.Value = True Then
            If wipe_format.Value = True Then
                MsgBox "Template 2 Private Model Tier 2 Wipe Out"
            Else
                MsgBox "Template 2 Private Model Tier 2 No Wipe Out"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select a tier"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a data type"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Please select a template"
End If

End Sub
```

And this is an example of one of the models. Basically it opens an Excel file generated by a different programme, copies one or two worksheets into the model (depending on template), there are worksheets in teh model with commented out formulas, so the macro uncomments them, hides those which are not needed and does some formatting.

```
Sub UploadData()
Dim FileOpenDial As Variant
Dim FileSaveAs As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim activeWB As Workbook
Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
Dim finstart As Range
Dim endcell As Range, startcell As Range
Dim yearsno As Range
Dim numrowsadj As Integer
Dim cfyearsno As Range
Dim numrows As Integer
Dim numrowscf As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim decimaltab As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim MySheets As Variant
Dim r As Range

'Import the data

'Optimize Code
  
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
FileOpenDial = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XML), *.XML", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If FileOpenDial = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileOpenDial)
    Sheets(Array("Accounts", "Types")).Select
    Sheets(Array("Accounts", "Types")).Copy Before:=activeWB.Sheets(1)
wb.Close savechanges:=False 'or True

'Save a file
FileSaveAs = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Exel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select Name To Save The File")
If FileSaveAs <> False Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileSaveAs, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If

'Unhide sheets
For Each MySheets In Array("FS", "CF", "tables", "Calcs", "tables_for_output", "Tier_I", "Tier_II")
    Worksheets(MySheets).Visible = True
Next

'Build tables from the data
Sheets("FS").Select

'Remove apostrophe from the formulas
For Each c In Range("D1:D250").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
Next c

'FillRight Formulas
Set yearsno = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Accounts").Range("F2:Z2")
numrows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(yearsno)
    If 5 - numrows >= 0 Then
        numrowsadj = 0
    Else: numrowsadj = 5 - numrows
    End If

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FS")
    Set startcell = .Range("D1")
    Set endcell = Cells(Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 3 + numrows + numrowsadj)
    Set finstart = .Range(startcell.Address & ":" & endcell.Address)
    finstart.FillRight
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FS").Range("C1").Select

'Build CF
Sheets("CF").Select

'Remove apostrophe from the formulas
For Each c In Range("F1:F160").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
Next c

'FillRight Formulas
Set cfyearsno = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FS").Range("C1:XFD1")
numrowscf = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(cfyearsno)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF")
    Set startcell = .Range("F1")
  
    If numrowscf = 3 Then
        Set endcell = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)
        Set finstart = .Range(startcell.Address & ":" & endcell.Address)
        finstart.FillRight
    ElseIf numrowscf > 3 Then
        Set endcell = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 2)
        Set finstart = .Range(startcell.Address & ":" & endcell.Address)
        finstart.FillRight
    Else
    End If
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF").Range("E1").Select

'Activite the Summary tables
Sheets("tables").Select

For Each c In Range("C1:G88").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
Next c

Sheets("tables").Range("B1").Select

'Activate Calcs
Sheets("Calcs").Select
'Remove apostrophe from the formulas
For Each c In Range("B1:H22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
Next c

'Activate tables_for_output
Sheets("tables_for_output").Select
For Each c In Range("B2:O43").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
Next c

'Activate Tier_I
Sheets("Tier_I").Select
For Each c In Range("D6:I15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
Next c

'Activate Tier_II
Sheets("Tier_II").Select
For Each c In Range("D6:I15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
Next c

'Hide the working worksheets
Sheets(Array("Model", "Calcs")).Visible = False

'Stop Optimize Code
'Call OptimizeCode_End

'ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True


'Replace Conditional formating with normal based on a checkbox

If Sheets("Model").Shapes("Check Box 7").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

Sheets("tables_for_output").Select

    Range("F4:O4").Select
    
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Interior.Color = r.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next r
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete

'Tier_I

Sheets("Tier_I").Select

    Range("F6:H15").Select

    For Each r In Selection
        r.Interior.Color = r.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next r
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete

Sheets("Tier_I").Range("C2").Select
    
'Tier_II

Sheets("Tier_II").Select

Range("F6:H15").Select

    For Each r In Selection
        r.Interior.Color = r.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next r
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tables_for_output").Select
    Sheets("tables_for_output").Range("A1").Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tier_II").Select
    Sheets("Tier_II").Range("C2").Select

'Hide a Tier sheet based on the selection

If Sheets("Calcs").Range("B24").Value = 1 Then
    Sheets("Tier_II").Visible = False
ElseIf Sheets("Calcs").Range("B24").Value = 2 Then
    Sheets("Tier_I").Visible = False
End If

'Formatting
'Columns Width
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FS").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.AutoFit
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Decimal Formatting
'tables
Sheets("tables").Select
Set decimaltab = [C2:E16,C25:E49,C62:E69,C71:E75,C77:E83]

For Each d In decimaltab.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
    If Abs(d.Value) < 20 And Round(d.Value, 0) <> 0 Then
        d.NumberFormat = "0.0;(0.0)"
    Else
        d.NumberFormat = "#,##0;(#,##0)"
        
   End If
Next d

'tables_for_output
Sheets("tables_for_output").Select
Set decimaltab = [B2:B3,B11:D15,B17:D18,B20:D23,B33:D34,B37:D39,B43:D43]

For Each d In decimaltab.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
    If Abs(d.Value) < 101 And Round(d.Value, 0) <> 0 Then
        d.NumberFormat = "0.0;(0.0)"
    Else
        d.NumberFormat = "#,##0;(#,##0)"
        
   End If
Next d

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

I just cannot figure out a good way to integrate the user form into the existing code. I guess I need to get the output of the user form in a form of variable and them to build an algorithm. But I do not know how to start.

Basically I need to achieve the following algorithm:

```
Fill User Form
    If any of the options are not selected ask user to do it

Run Upload Data sub
Optimise

    Open external Excel file
        If Template 1 Selected Then
            Import Accounts and Types sheets
        Else
            Import Accounts sheet
        End If
    Save file under a different name
Unhide hiden templates
    If Template 1 Then
        If datatype Private Then
            Unhide FS_1, CF_1, tables, calcs, tables_for_output, Tier 1, Tier 2
            Rename FS_1 and CF_1 to FS and CF
        Else
            Unhide FS_1, CF_1, tables
            Rename FS_1 and CF_1 to FS and CF
    Else
        If datatype Private Then
            Unhide FS_2, CF_2, tables, calcs, tables_for_output, Tier 1, Tier 2
            Rename FS_2 and CF_2 to FS and CF
        Else
            Unhide FS_2, CF_2
            Rename FS_2 and CF_2 to FS and CF
        End If
    End If
Activite Templates
    Activate FS
    Activate CF
    Activate tables
    If datatype Private
        Activate calcs
        Acivate tables_for_output
        Activate Tier 1
        Activate Tier 2
Otimisation ends

Tidying up
    Hide unneeded sheets
        If datatype Private Then
            If Tier 1 Then
                Hide Model, cacls, Tier 2
            Else
                Hide Model, calcs, Tier 1
        Else
            Hide Model
        End If
    If datatype Private replace conditional formatting with normal
        If Tier 1
            In tables_for_otput, Tier 1
        Else
            in tables_for_output, Tier 2
        End If
    
Additional Formattng
    If datatype Public
        Format FS, CF, tables
    Else
        Format FS, CF, table, tables for output
    End If

Workbook Save

Sub End
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Use the values from the userform in your `UploadDate` sub? If so, where do you need them and what exactly is stopping you from using them?

Comment: I want to run a particular parts of the code based on the criteria selected by users. They are not values. At the moment, for example, if a user has data from Template 1, Public datatype, they use one model, if it's Template 2, Private datatype, Tier 1, they have to use a different model. So I currently have 4 files, which makes it inconvenient for users to use and difficult for me to update, if I make changes in the common part of the code. So I want to merge these models into one. So a user will open it, select a template, a datatype ect. and run the appropriate code.

Comment: So you'd prefer to work off a (hidden) template and adjust where needed based on the criteria and then show the adjusted template to the user?

Comment: I have added at the end of the OT what I want to achieve,

Comment: I wonder if I can define sets of variables for each outcome of the user form and then use them in the code?

Comment: A start could be with checking if the user has chosen an option out of each selection. If there's something missing, MsgBox "Please select.." and then `Exit Sub`. If the option check passes, code continues with copying from a default template and with each check which option got chosen, you call a Sub like `Sub templSelect(ByVal templ As String)` which would change the default to the fit of the template with templ as the variable you can fill when doing the first option check; and so on for the other options.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've done the check if the options are selected. So  the first option is a template. It affects which worksheets are imported, which are unhidden and which are renamed. So should I do something like:
`Sub templSelect(ByVal templ As String) 
    If UserForm1.radiotempl1.Value = True Then 
        templ = "templ1" 
    Else 
        templ = "templ2" 
    End If 
End Sub` 

And then use in IF statement in the main subroutine?

Comment: The point of the variable when calling the sub `ByVal templ As String` was to pass to the sub which template was chosen and then adjust what's necessary based on that. You could copy from the chosen templ to a new sheet, then call the sheet the same as you would with the other template and work on that sheet in the next subs. `Sheets(templ).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)` with `ActiveSheet.Name = "YourRapport"`
If I have time this weekend, I'll flesh out what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will play with it, but if you could provide a simple example of that it would be be much easier for me as I have never used ByVal before.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on it last weekend but got interrupted rather early on. Apologies for the delay.
The `ByVal` wasn't really needed here, I may have worded myself incorrectly. Here's the documentation in case you'd like to read up on it: [Byval & ByRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference)

As for the code, I tried to get it done the way you mentioned but wipe_out was not included in your Sub? So couldn't implement it either.

Hope the code works and was the way you specified:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UploadData()
    Dim FileOpenDial As Variant
    Dim FileSaveAs As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook, activeWB As Workbook
    Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
    Dim finstart As Range, endcell As Range, startcell As Range
    Dim yearsno As Range, cfyearsno As Range
    Dim numrows As Long, numrowscf As Long, numrowsadj As Long 'I prefer to not have number rows in Integer due to limitations of size
    Dim c As Range, d As Range, r As Range, decimaltab As Range
    Dim MySheets As String, tier As String
    Dim templ As Integer, dType As Integer, wipe As Integer
    
    'Checking user form
    If radiotempl1.Value Then templ = 1
    ElseIf radiotempl2.Value Then templ = 2
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a template"
    End If
    
    If dataType.Value = "Public" Then
        dType = 1
    ElseIf dataType.Value = "Private" Then
        dType = 2
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a data type"
    End If
    
    If wipe_format.Value Then wipe = 1
    
    If radiotier1.Value Then tier = "Tier_1"
    If radiotier2.Value Then tier = "Tier_2"
    Else
        If dType = 2 Then
            MsgBox "Please select a tier"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    If templ + dType < 2 Then Exit Sub
    
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    FileOpenDial = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XML), *.XML", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If FileOpenDial = False Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileOpenDial)
    'you mentioned "copies one or two worksheets into the model (depending on the template) but I'm not sure which way you wanted this
    Sheets(Array("Accounts", "Types")).Copy Before:=activeWB.Sheets(1) 'avoid select as much as possible
    wb.Close savechanges:=False 'or True
    
    'Save a file
    FileSaveAs = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Exel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select Name To Save The File")
    If FileSaveAs <> False Then
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileSaveAs, _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    End If
    
    copySheet "FS", templ 'this is to copy the right sheet and delete the FS if it alreasdy existed from a previous time you ran the code
    copySheet "CF", templ
    
    
    Set yearsno = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Accounts").Range("F2:Z2")
    
    With Sheets("FS")
        'Remove apostrophe from the formulas
        For Each c In .Range("D1:D250").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
        Next c
        
        numrows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(yearsno)
        If 5 - numrows >= 0 Then
            numrowsadj = 0
        Else: numrowsadj = 5 - numrows
        End If
    
        Set startcell = .Range("D1")
        Set endcell = Cells(Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 3 + numrows + numrowsadj)
        Set finstart = .Range(startcell.Address & ":" & endcell.Address)
        finstart.FillRight
        Set cfyearsno = .Range("C1:XFD1")
        numrowscf = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(cfyearsno)
    End With
        
    With Sheets("CF")
        'Remove apostrophe from the formulas
        For Each c In Range("F1:F160").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
        Next c
        Set startcell = .Range("F1")
  
        If numrowscf = 3 Then
            Set endcell = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)
            Set finstart = .Range(startcell.Address & ":" & endcell.Address)
            finstart.FillRight
        ElseIf numrowscf > 3 Then
            Set endcell = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 2)
            Set finstart = .Range(startcell.Address & ":" & endcell.Address)
            finstart.FillRight
        Else
        End If
    End With
    
    With Sheets("tables")
        For Each c In .Range("C1:G88").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
        Next c
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Calcs")
        For Each c In Range("B1:H22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
        Next c
    End With
    
    With Sheets("tables_for_output")
        For Each c In Range("B2:O43").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
        Next c
    End With
        
    'no need to hide sheets if you keep them hidden :)
    
    Calculate
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    With Sheets("tables_for_output")
        For Each r In Range("F4:O4")
            r.Interior.Color = r.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next r
        Range("F4:O4").FormatConditions.Delete
    End With
    
    If dType = 2 Then
        With Sheets(tier) 'same here as last time with tier
            For Each c In .Range("D6:I15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, "'", "")
            Next c
            For Each r In Range("F6:H15")
                r.Interior.Color = r.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
            Next r
            Range("F6:H15").FormatConditions.Delete
            .Visible = True
        End With
    End With
    
    'Formatting
    'Columns Width
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FS").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    'Decimal Formatting
    'tables
    With Sheets("tables")
    Set decimaltab = Union(.Range("C2:E16"), .Range("C25:E49"), .Range("C62:E69"), .Range("C71:E75"), .Range("C77:E83"))
    
    For Each d In decimaltab.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
        If Abs(d.Value) < 20 And Round(d.Value, 0) <> 0 Then
            d.NumberFormat = "0.0;(0.0)"
        Else
            d.NumberFormat = "#,##0;(#,##0)"
            
       End If
    Next d
    
    'tables_for_output
    With Sheets("tables_for_output")
        Set decimaltab = Union(.Range("B2:B3"), .Range("B11:D15"), .Range("B17:D18"), .Range("B20:D23"), .Range("B33:D34"), .Range("B37:D39"), .Range("B43:D43"))
        
        For Each d In decimaltab.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
            If Abs(d.Value) < 101 And Round(d.Value, 0) <> 0 Then
                d.NumberFormat = "0.0;(0.0)"
            Else
                d.NumberFormat = "#,##0;(#,##0)"
                
           End If
        Next d
        .Activate
    'You will have to decide which sheet you actually want to be presented first but I got rid of the copious use of .Select
    'For now it's this one
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Sub copySheet(shtName As String, templNo As Integer)
    If WorksheetExists(shtName) Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtName).Delete
    shtName = shtName & "_" & templNo
    Sheets(shtName).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = Left(shtName, 2)
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask